# no space between text and icon in ul element

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a little problem with the ie7 and ul list element.

In ie8/9 and firefox there is an additional empty space between the icon and text:

[image]

In ie7 unfortunatelly it looks that:

[image]

Styles for the ul list:

```
margin-top: 5px;
    list-style-image: url('../Images/listItem10.png');
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 5px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    float: left;
```

Unfortunatelly any attemps to create a hack for it doesn't work.
Please for any suggestion how can I achieve it.

Comment: What happens when you include margin-left:5px in your class? as well as padding-left

Comment: it moves the entire block (icon+text) with 5px, not only text

Comment: What about making a IE7 stylesheet? http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: what if you try to add a `*text-indent: 5px` ?

Comment: What is the css for your `li` element? Although I think Rohit has posted a solution that will work for you

Comment: *text-indent: 5px works like margin-left - it moves entire block. For li I have no additional styles except from the Eric Meyers reset.css. I going to try the Rohit answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...........................

Hi now used to `background` **image** not `list-style-image`

```
margin-top: 5px;
    list-style:none;
background:url('../Images/listItem10.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    padding-left: 5px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    float: left;
```

Comment: When I change the list-style-image to background on the ul element, it works only for the first element on the list. So I moved the background to the li elements and now on ie7 it works great. Unfortunatelly now it works properly only in ie7 ;) I think I will have to create a css file only for this one browser like @Simon Pertersen suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. try to include the image as a "background-image" in the

and add a padding to the

itself. Right now the padding will make the

move to the right because it is set on the :

```
|
|...|#'Text'
|...|#'Text2'
|
```

Adding the padding to the

would make the text move to the right, but not the background-image

```
|
||#...'Text'
||#...'Text'
|
```

Maybe this works :)
(I hope the 'illustrations' give you a better idea of what I try to say... :D )